# Media queries are correct for this example?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Im a beginner in css and I dont know if I understand media queries properly.

To have a css structure like this:

```
general css 
     fonts, paddings, colors, etc 

css for small screens (up to 499px) 

     specific css for this resolution 

 css for large screen (more than 500px) 

      specific css for this resolution 

css specific for impression
      specific css for this case, for example different text color, etc
```

Is the correct media query structure like this?

```
/* GENERIC CSS */ 

/* CSS for small screens */ 

@media only screen and (max-width: 499px) { ... }

/* CSS for small screens */

@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) { ... }

/* CSS for some specific changes like text color, etc for printing on paper */

@media print {...}
```

Comment: This looks perfectly fine, from my understanding :D
I referred to w3schools. Also, its HTML, why not give it a test? You can sample different devices using chrome dev tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in general, CSS files should be structured with General CSS on top of your media queries.

Then if you'd like to change the CSS at a smaller screen size, you would use a `max-width` media query. Think of it like this, `@media (max-width: 568px)`, this means that the maximum screen size this css will apply is 568 pixels. Anything greater than that and the CSS will no longer apply.

Same goes for `min-width`. `@media (min-width: 569px)` means the minimum width this CSS will apply is 569 pixels. Anything lower than 569 (for example, 568px) pixels will no longer apply. The screen must be AT LEAST 569 pixels to pick it up.

And print is straight-forward, it's what will show when you are printing the page.

Hope that helps! From what you posted, that structure is 100% right.